# For a system containing three reductants, can a combined reduction potential be determined?

Tags: redox, reduction-potential

I've modelled a system and found that there are three major complexes present at equilibrium, all of which I hope will act as reductants when I add an additional, oxidised species. Each of the three complexes has a different concentration in the solution, and each has an associated reduction potential.

Is there any way to find an overall reduction potential for my reactor, based on some combination of reduction potentials?

I could be missing something fundamental!

Comment: There is no such thing as a combined reduction potential. Instead, there are potentials of individual species, and those will tell you which of them is going to get oxidized first.